# I am missing two binary sources from the 'Other Software' list. Where have these binaries gone and how do I get them back?

Tags: updates, binary

I have upgraded to Ubuntu 17.10 (artful) but have found that I am missing two binaries on the 'Other Software' list in the Software and Updates manager. Both the 'important security updates' (main restricted) and the 'recommended updates' (multiverse) binaries are missing and only the source code ones are there (and not ticked). I think these missing binaries should be there already, installed with the os (Ubuntu 17.10). How do I get them back? Would I be able to add these if I had the URIs for them?

Here is my log:

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS _Xenial Xerus_ - Release amd64 (20170215.2)]/ xenial main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful main restricted
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful multiverse
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial multiverse
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://ie.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu artful partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner

deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security main restricted
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security universe
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-security multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial main universe restricted multiverse
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security multiverse
deb https://dl.bintray.com/hawkeye116477/waterfox-deb release main # disabled on upgrade to artful
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ artful partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ xenial partner
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu artful-updates universe main restricted multiverse<br>
```

And here is the output of 'grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/':

```
    :~# grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jaap_karssenberg-ubuntu-zim-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu artful main # disabled on upgrade to artful
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jaap_karssenberg-ubuntu-zim-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-testing-xenial.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu artful main # disabled on upgrade to artful
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-testing-xenial.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/skype-stable.list.save:deb [arch=amd64] https://repo.skype.com/deb stable main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list:deb https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./ # disabled on upgrade to artful
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list.save:deb https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./ # disabled on upgrade to artful
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-testing-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-testing-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jaap_karssenberg-ubuntu-zim-xenial.list.distUpgrade:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jaap_karssenberg-ubuntu-zim-xenial.list.distUpgrade:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu artful main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu artful main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-testing-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu artful main # disabled on upgrade to artful
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/linuxgndu-ubuntu-sqlitebrowser-testing-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/linuxgndu/sqlitebrowser-testing/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/megasync.list.distUpgrade:deb https://mega.nz/linux/MEGAsync/xUbuntu_16.04/ ./
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu artful main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/teejee2008-ubuntu-ppa-artful.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu artful main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jaap_karssenberg-ubuntu-zim-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu artful main # disabled on upgrade to artful
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/jaap_karssenberg-ubuntu-zim-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/jaap.karssenberg/zim/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/audio-recorder-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:deb http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/audio-recorder-ubuntu-ppa-xenial.list.save:# deb-src http://ppa.launchpad.net/audio-recorder/ppa/ubuntu xenial main
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the complete contents of your file `/etc/apt/sources.list`

Comment: Other software tab doesn't have any of the repositories you've listed by default. They should all be under Ubuntu Software tab, namely main, universe, restricted, multiverse and source code. You should only have Canonical Partner under Other Software tab.

Comment: I didn't know that. There are source codes in the list for those two and on previous Ubuntu installations I have had the missing ones there.

Comment: Some sources may be located in `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/` directory. Usually they went disabled on upgrade. Please post contents of `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` to the question.

Comment: Okay, here it goes but I hope some-one will format it for me (please) as I'm hopeless at it.